# Получение значения из C++ в QML

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Мне нужно нанести на лейбл QML количество онлайна при старте приложения.

Помогите реализовать

Код онлайна я давно написал, но в QML начал работать со вчерашнего дня и представления о нем никакого не имею.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica, Там указано только создание. А мне нужно на готовый label QML нанести определенное значение

Comment: @ЭдуардВесторнович ну то есть Accessing Loaded QML Objects by Object Name и Accessing Members of a QML Object Type from C++ — это не о том? :(

Answer (score 3):

Нужно завести на стороне С++ переменную Q_PROPERTY в которую будет писаться кол-во онлайна.
Например:

`Q_PROPERTY(int count READ count NOTIFY countChanged)`

Зарегистрировать свой С++ класс в QML так:

```
 qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("MyClass", 1, 0, "myClass");
```

Затем на стороне QML:

```
import MyClass 1.0

Label {
    text: myClass.count
}
```